# After + past simple, is the action always completed?

Tags: grammar, differences, tenses, past-tense

In the following sentence:

> After I read the magazine, I decided to go out.

For native speakers, does it mean:

1. that I read the whole magazine and then went out
2. that I read some pages and after a while (of reading) I went out
3. could be both

My question is - I assume that "after I read" expresses simply "after the act of reading", regardless of whether I finished the book or just a few pages?

Comment: I would think the former

Comment: You raise two issues: 1) the question in your title 2) does "I read (past tense) the magazine" imply that I read all of it? Please could you clarify which one you want the answer to? Is your question concerned specifically with the verb "to read", or with any verb which can denote an activity which takes time and might be interrupted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without additional context, all that can be assumed from this construction is that *some* reading occurred. There is not enough information to infer how much was read, and the construction does not imply completion of anything beyond "the act of reading".

Comment: Thanks, and what if there was the past perfect? After I had read the magazine, I went out.

Comment: Again, without additional contextual information indicating how much was read, grammatically this simply means that some reading occurred in the past. The addition of the past perfect really just specifies that the speaker finished the act of reading, not necessarily the object being read.

Comment: @Jack: Is there a 'past perfect' in the question?  Both clauses are simple past. I agree with your comment "Again, without additional contextual information indicating how much was read, grammatically this simply means that some reading occurred in the past."